# Where's a good place to train up to level 50?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I defeated Cyrus for the first time at Veilstone and I'm going to Mt. Coronet to fight Mars, Jupiter, Cyrus and Dialga.

My weakest pokemon is at level 30 and my strongest is at level 43.

Where can I train up to level 45-50?

My Team:

- Infernape Lvl 43
- Luxray lvl 40
- Staraptor lvl 37
- Gyarados lvl 35
- Graveler lvl 34
- Kadabra lvl 30

Comment: Hey, Jvam, welcome to Arqade!  I've removed your team information, as that's too specific to help everybody.  Any answers you get should still help you find places to train.  As for trading, that's a separate question; I'd recommend asking that by itself.

Comment: Thanks man. Would you know where could i train up to level 50? Snowpoint city perhaps?

Comment: Afraid I don't know.  I haven't played Pokemon for quite some time.  Lots of us do play it, though!  You should get some decent answers.

Comment: I think it's ok to include team information - it dictates which zones are easier then others based on pokemon types that spawn there. That being said you could write it in a comment @Jvam to keep the question short and simple.

Comment: Edited with team information

Comment: Take it like a man and get in there! I beat Cynthia in Platinum with level 48s across the board going into the Elite Four and that was the first Pokemon game I actually owned.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, Mount Coronet would probably be the best place for this. Entering from Route 216, the Pokemon in this area are in the low to mid 30s, and they get stronger as you go up, ending up at about level 40 on average at the top. The area around Lake Acuity has about the same levels as higher up on Mount Coronet, and then Route 222 has Pokemon in the low to mid 40s, which should help boost your team up to level 50.

Comment: I see. i'll check those places. Thanks for the tips :D

Answer (score 0):

I am taking advice from [this website](https://www.dragonflycave.com/sinnoh/places-to-train). If you want to train your Kadabra, you should train in Iron Island mainly (from the website), despite being extremely inaccessible. But, be warned of the Graveler there, they can Selfdestruct! Besides, those Pokémon might not be much of a challenge for you thanks to Kadabra's high Special Attack stat. If you don't like Iron Island, you can train at routes 218 or 221. Once those Pokémon get to level 33ish, you can start training at Acuity Lakefront and Route 217. By level 35, all of your Pokémon can begin training at Mt. Coronet 2F. If the wild Pokémon there don't help, you can use the Vs. Seeker at some places; some of the trainer's Pokémon may get into the 30s where you are. Trust me; the Vs. Seeker will help you. It assisted me in my training for the Elite Four in Platinum; it'll help you! But, not every trainer has a higher-leveled team in Diamond compared to Platinum (my game of expertise). So, go with those places or Vs. Seeker.

Let me know if you have any problems. I hope this helps!